# Count number of records by date in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model similar to the following:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, db_index=True)
    review = models.TextField()  
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I'd like to query the database to get the total number of reviews for a venue grouped by day.  The MySQL query would be:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime_created), count(id) 
FROM REVIEW 
WHERE venue_id = 2
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_created);
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in Django?  I could just use

```
Review.objects.filter(venue__pk=2)
```

and parse the results in the view, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This should work (using the same MySQL specific function you used):

```
Review.objects.filter(venue__pk=2)
    .extra({'date_created' : "date(datetime_created)"})
    .values('date_created')
    .annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

Comment: That's like my answer but better!!

Comment: Was sadly missing the .extra().. Very powerful .Thanks !

Comment: Something I can't get it ,,, using .extra() BEFORE the .values() have a different result then using it AFTER the .values() clause ?!!
Any explanation master ?!

Comment: I'm a little late here @radev but here's the answer you're looking for:

"If you use a values() clause after an extra() call, any fields defined by a select argument in the extra() must be explicitly included in the values() call. Any extra() call made after a values() call will have its extra selected fields ignored."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: Right, that's a result of somewhat mysterious behavior of the [values() clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values). 


**BUT** also keep in mind that using this in querysets with ordeing aplied (either through the _order_by()_ part of a queryset or the fields that are used in the default ordering on a model) **won't work until you**  explicitly **clear** any ordering in the query -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

Comment: Nowadays, [`.extra` should only be used as a last resort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).  Is there any alternative?

Comment: How to get zero count if count is less than 1 .

Comment: Bit late to the party, but you can bin the `extra` and do simply `.values('date_created__date')` to achieve the cast nowadays. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date (there's also related ones to get `year`, `month`, etc.)

Answer (score 28):

Now that `Extra()` is being depreciated a more appropriate answer would use [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) such as [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Now the OP's question would be answered as follows

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay

Review.objects.all()
    .annotate(date=TruncDay('datetime_created'))
    .values("date")
    .annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
    .order_by("-date")
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis? `.annotate(date=TruncDay('datetime_created')`

Comment: Still works in 2021!

Comment: Just used this example in 2022!

Answer (score 17):

Just for completeness, since extra() is aimed for deprecation, one could use this approach:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import DateTime

Review.objects.all().\
    annotate(month=DateTime("timestamp", "month", pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC"))).\
    values("month").\
    annotate(created_count=Count('id')).\
    order_by("-month")
```

It worked for me in django 1.8, both in sqlite and MySql databases.

Comment: also you can use django timezone utils instead of pytz.timezone
`django.utils.timezone.get_default_timezone`

Comment: This seems to have been moved under [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.Extract) in Django 1.10

Answer (score 14):

If you were storing a date field, you could use this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Review.objects.filter(venue__pk = 2)
    .values('date').annotate(event_count = Count('id'))
```

Because you're storing datetime, it's a little more complicated, but this should offer a good starting point. Check out the aggregation docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Answer (score 3):

Also you can define custom function:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

# create custom sql function
class ExtractDateFunction(Func):
    function = "DATE" # thats the name of function, the way it mapped to sql

# pass this function to annotate
Review.objects.filter(venue__pk=2)
      .annotate(date_created=ExtractDateFunction("datetime_created"))
      .values('date_created')
      .annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

Just make sure that your DB engine supports DATE function

Comment: The `ExtractDateFunction` defined here won't support timezone modification as seen here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/

You can get the query to respect timezones, as of 1.10, by using `TruncDate` (see that link) instead. (As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930880/221533))