# Get daily counts of objects from Django

Tags: django, django-aggregation

I have a Django model with a `created` timestamp and I'd like to get the counts of objects created on each day. I was hoping to use the aggregation functionality in Django but I can't figure out how to solve my problem with it. Assuming that doesn't work I can always fall back to just getting all of the dates with values_list but I'd prefer to give the work to Django or the DB. How would you do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278076/count-number-of-records-by-date-in-django

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alex pointed to the right answer in the comment:

[Count number of records by date in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278076/count-number-of-records-by-date-in-django)
Credit goes to [ara818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223430/ara818)

`Guidoism.objects.extra({'created':"date(created)"}).values('created').annotate(created_count=Count('id'))`

```
from django.db.models import Count

Guidoism.objects \
    # get specific dates (not hours for example) and store in "created" 
    .extra({'created':"date(created)"})
    # get a values list of only "created" defined earlier
    .values('created')
    # annotate each day by Count of Guidoism objects
    .annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

I learn new tricks every day reading stack.. awesome!

Comment: `extra` is listed as deprecated soon. Try `TruncDay` instead now https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746532/2283261

Answer (score 0):

Use the [count](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) method:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(published_on=datetime.date(2011, 4, 1)).count()
```

Comment: sounds a bit expensive to count every day though