# Django--change datetime field to a date field

Tags: sql, django, date, datetime

say I have a model like this:

```
class Arrival(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='client')
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I would like to plot a graph with number of unique client visits at each date.

My current approach is to use:

```
Arrival.objects.values('client','time')
```

afterwards convert all the datetime field to a date field. Use python library to get a list of unique date, and then iterate through the clients to find out how many clients visit per date.

Do anyone have a more efficient approach please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my answer here:

[Get daily counts of objects from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878614/get-daily-counts-of-objects-from-django)

```py
(Arrival.objects
    # get specific dates (not hours for example) and store in "created" 
    .extra({'created':"date(time)"})
    # get a values list of only "created" defined earlier
    .values('created')
    # annotate each day by Count of Arrival objects
    .annotate(created_count=Count('id')))
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for the comment. But I think this thing does not filter out the duplicate visits. What method would you recommend to only count those ids which are unique?

Comment: how are you defining uniqueness. You want to count visits per day but once per client?