# How to group by events by year and month in django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-models

I tried multiple approach, but could not come to solution.

I have event model like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I want to group events by year and then months:

### 2013

Jan

1. Event 1
2. Event 2

Feb

1. Event 1
2. Event 2

### 2014

Jan

1. Event 1
2. Event 2

I am only taking start_date while doing sorting.

At last I was thinking this would work, but it doesn't:

```
Event.objects.values_list('start_date__year').annotate(dcount=Count('start_date__year'))
```

Comment: Answered your question. I hope it was enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you how to group them separately. This is how *I* would go about it, but please note that my knowledge of django is not the best in the world.

```
Event.objects.filter(end_date__year=2013)
```

This way you will get all the events in 2013.

You can further filter them to get the month.

```
Event.objects.filter(end_date__year=2013).filter(end_date__month='01')
```

This would get you all the dates in February. You could simply use a `ModelManager` to manage these custom queries, since you will be doing them a lot, and then you can just call them in your views.

You can make a `ModelManager` like so:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_year(self, year):
        Event.objects.filter(date__year=year)
```

And you can simply call it by, `Event.objects.get_by_year(2013)`. You can do this after you change your `objects` property in your `Model`, like so:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    objects = EventManager
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Well, I am aware of that. It gets a bit messy and becomes long to go that way. Like, I will have to do same for all the months etc. 
Will be probably last resort.

Comment: @neokya: Actually it wont, just abstract that away in a `ModelManager`, and that will make like a lot easier.

Comment: I actually wanted grouped output in single query itself. Looks that's not really ideal thing to do. I will query and then group by year and month. 

I think above answer is way to go in django. So, I am accepting it.

Comment: Also, please Event.objects.filter to just self.get_query_set()

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `groupby()` function after you have queried the data.

Here is an example.  Instead of date() you would use month instead.
[Django - Group By with Date part alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257128/django-group-by-with-date-part-alone)