# Django/Python: How to group queryset results by date?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a model for image uploads, that looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime

class ImageItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    original_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = img_get_file_path)
```

I want to query all instances of ImageItem that belong to a particular user, and group them according to *date uploaded*. For example, for some user, I want a group for April 9 2013, another for April 12 2013, etc. (assuming that they uploaded one or more images on those dates).

I'm thinking I run a simple query, like,

```
joes_images = ImageItem.objects.filter(user__username='joe')
```

**But then how could I group them by day published?** (assuming he did not publish every day, only on some days)

The function would have to return all the groups of images.

Comment: Have you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: No, I hadn't, and that definitely solves the first half of my question. Here, the `upload_date` field is a datetime.datetime object, which means no two upload_date values are the same. I would like to group only according to date, not time. How would I do that?

Comment: I think you have to use `.extra()` for that, you can't `.order_by()` on a datetimefield unfortunately :(

Comment: You could however convert it to a DateTimeField instead and be done with it. Ie. have one field for grouping on and one field for doing whatever else on. (This is a bit superflous but it'd work)

Comment: Ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/2283913/165603 , you could do it in `extra` by typing cast datetime to date. If applicable, writing a SQL in `raw()` is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you do as following?

```
joes_images = ImageItem.objects.filter(user__username='joe')  # your code
upload_dates = set([(i.year, i.month, i.day) for i in joes_images])  # set of upload_date
joes_images_separated = dict([(d, []) for d in upload_dates])
for d in upload_dates:
    for i in joes_images:
        if (i.year, i.month, i.day) == d:
            joes_images_separated[d].append(i)
```

Here, `upload_dates` is a set of dates in `joes_images` and you get `joes_images_separated` as a dict (keys are dates, values are lists of `joes_images` for each date).

I'm sorry for a little dirty code. I think this works. for your information.

Comment: You do not need 2 for loops. Get rid of `for d in upload_dates:` and the if statement and just construct the date key `d` for every image in `joes_images`