# Count data by day

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this queryset function to count the field `created` but I would love to count by day and not how it is currently because I want to make chart with this data.

```
           queryset = Model.objects.filter(
            user=user
        ).values("created").annotate(
            Count("created")).order_by("created")
```

Result:

```
 [{"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:05:50Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:05:53Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:05:56Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:26:37Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:26:41Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:27:10Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T09:27:15Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T10:12:40Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T10:12:46Z"}, {"created__count": 1, "created": "2013-10-01T10:12:53Z"}]
```

This there some way to count by day like 11/11: Count 20, 12/11: Count 22.

Should I compute this data after I got it from the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `Count('created__day')`. At least `created__day` should work in the filtering part of the query, so intuitively, it should also work with `Count`.

**EDIT:**

...nope, it doesn't work, but you might find a solution in [Count number of records by date in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278076/count-number-of-records-by-date-in-django).

So basically you have to use `.extra(...)` combined with some (potentially non-standard) SQL functions that extract just a part of a datetime (e.g. the MySQL `DATE()`), and then use the resulting field to `Count`.

Comment: Yes, I did it I got a FieldError. Join on field 'created' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.