# Group objects by dates

Tags: django, python-datetime, django-1.9

```
clicks = SellerClick.objects.extra({'date' : "date(timestamp)"}).values('date').annotate(count=Count('timestamp'))
```

The model has a datetime field called `timestamp` that was are using. I first, convert the datetime field to just a date field. Then the rest is guessing. I need to group by, and then count how many objects are of each date.

So the desired result would be a date, then a count, based on how many objects have that date in the `timestamp` field.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use annotate over extra

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL  

SellerClick.objects.annotate(
    date=RawSQL('date(date_joined)',[]),
).values('date').annotate(count=Count('date')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got everything but an initial queryset there. The extra sql you're passing doesn't include a select so you need to give it something to act on.

```
clicks = SellerClick.objects.all()
    .extra({'date' : "date(timestamp)"})
    .values('date')
    .annotate(count=Count('timestamp'))
```

Ref: [StackOverflow: Count number of records by date in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278076/count-number-of-records-by-date-in-django)

Comment: What if I use filter instead of `all()`?

Comment: Same principle, you'd just have to give it something to query, obviously. You could even put a select in the `.extra()` and eliminate `.all()` or `.filter()` completely, but the use case seems better lent to the way you're already doing it.