# How to group by date from timestamp field with Django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have this MySQL specific query

```
SELECT SUM(trip_amount) as tp , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(request_time))  as timestamp 
FROM trip_master 
WHERE trip_master.date > 1493836200 
AND trip_master.date < 1493922600 
AND trip_master.id = 6  
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Implemented this query in Django,

```
Trip.objects.filter(id=userid,date__gt = start,date__lt = end).annotate(trip_amount = Sum('trip_amount')).extra({'timestamp':'DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(request_time))'})
```

As defined I have to convert time stamp to date to have grouping from dates. Has reached at the almost level but not getting group by dates.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL  

Trip.objects.filter(
    id=userid,
    date__gt=start,
    date__lt=end
).annotate(
    timestamp=RawSQL('DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(request_time))', [])
).values(
    'timestamp'
).annotate(
    trip_amount=Sum('trip_amount')
)
```

See [Group objects by dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152402/group-objects-by-dates)